# Failure to Update Rows in GridDB

Tags: node.js, griddb

I am using GridDB for the Data Analysis project on a CSV file related to loans and wanted to update some records. The file and the code are as follows:

[image: File of Records]

```js
Container<Integer, Row> container = store.getContainer(studentinfo);
if ( container == null ){
  throw new Exception("Container not found.");
}
container.setAutoCommit(false);

Query<Row> query = container.query("SELECT * WHERE id = 1069971");
RowSet<Row> rs = query.fetch(true); 

while( rs.hasNext() ){
  Row row = rs.next();
  row.setInteger(3, 88);
  rs.update(row);
}

container.commit();

System.out.println("Updated Row");
```

But I received the following error:

```
[Server]: 140039/145039

[Description] (Curser not locked)
```

The data in the csv is loaded into the container and then updated through the container. What does this error mean and how to resolve it?